# i have a 150cc gy6s chinese scooter my starter clutch went out so i replaced it now all it does is click at the solonoid

Tags: starting, scooter

i have a 150cc gy6 scooter my starter clutch went out now all it does is click at the solenoid I have also replaced the solenoid and the stator what am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm wondering if you didn't adjust or install the clutch correctly and now it grips too much.

Comment: When the starter was disassembled, are the brushes worn down? Well worn starters wear out their brushes until the starter motor no longer powers up.